# Can't make SESSION to work

Tags: php, html, session, authentication

Here is the story. I'm coding (fairly) simple login in PHP with no database. Yes, I do agree, it's unsecure and dirty way to do it but I'm just learning. Anyway, the code is simple and everything works fine except the session. I'm trying to make attacker stop accessing `panel.php` which is protected page only administrator can enter. The `index.php` is login page with form.

**config.php**

```
<?php
$loginToken =   '123456';

$uname      =   'test';
$upass      =   '123123';


$a_login        =   'index.php';
$a_panel        =   'panel.php';
$a_list     =   'list.php';
$a_add      =   'add.php';
$a_other        =   'other.php';
?>
```

**index.php** (Login form - for some reason, SO does not allow me to paste the code correctly):

> ```
> <?php
> // Load & start a session before everything
> session_start();
>
> // If session is already loaded, get into panel area
> if ($_SESSION['login'] == "1") {
>         Header("Location: $a_panel");
> }
>
> // Load configuration file
> include_once('cfg/config.php');
>
> if (isset ( $_POST ['username'] )) {
>         $password = $_POST ['password'];
>         $username = $_POST ['username'];
>
>         if ($password == $upass && $username == $uname) {
>                 header ( "Location: $a_panel" );
>                 exit (); }
> }
> ?><html>
> <head>
>         <title>Test</title>
>         <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css" media="all" />
> </head>
> <body>
>
> <br /><br />
> <center><a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo_b.png" /></a></center>
> <br /><br />
>
> <?php
>         if (isset($_GET['nToken']))     // A little bit of security (index.php?nToken=123456)
>         {
>                 if ($_GET['nToken'] == $loginToken) { ?>
>                 <form id="login" action="" method="post">
>                   <fieldset id="inputs">
>                       <input name='username' id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" autofocus required>  
>                       <input name='password' id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
>                   </fieldset>
>                   <fieldset id="actions">
>                       <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Log in">
>                   </fieldset>
>                 </form>
> <?php
>         }
>         }
> echo '
> </body>
> </html>';
> ?>
> ```

**panel.php** (Administrator area)

```
<?php
session_start();
    // Insert a config file
    require_once('cfg/config.php');

    // Check if logged (and if loaded display buttons)
    if ($_SESSION['login'] == "1") {
?>

<head>
    <title>
        Admin panel @ TEST
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bg.css" media="all" />
    <center><img src="images/header_1.png" /></center>

<div class="hot-container">
    <p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-blue">Listing</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-blue">Add new</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-blue">Settings</a>
    </p>
    <p>
    </p>
</div>

<?php
}
?>
```

As far as I know, code should work fine as `session_start()` is posted everywhere where it needs to be (except config.php) but session is not registered. When I access the `panel.php` with information I enter into form (from configuration file) I get a blank page, thus, that is not everything. Even if I access the page by entering "/panel.php" into URL, I get blank page.

Now I'm curious is it just me and my level of knowledge or there is some correction I have to do in php.ini :) Just to note I was trying to get as much info from SO with same questions before but didn't work no matter what.

Thanks!

Comment: blank page is usually PHP errors. What does your error log say?

Comment: add a print_r($_SESSION); after session_start() and show us result

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't say anything. I didn't use error_reporting().

EDIT: @FaceOfJock 
- index.php = Array ( [login] => )
- panel.php (after succesful login) = Array ( [login] => )

Comment: can you put code that assign value to your session

Comment: Thank you for your help @FaceOfJock! I manage to make script working by replacing some syntax. I didn't know `$_SESSION['login'] = "1"` and `$_SESSION["login"] = "1"` are two different things. I though they are the same so I somewhere placed "`'`" and somewhere "`"`". Thank you both once again. Regards.

Comment: add an answer to close this question